# How to add bi-directional manytomanyfields in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my models.py i have something like:

```
class LocationGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Report(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    locationgroups = models.ManyToManyField(LocationGroup)
```

admin.py (standard):

```
admin.site.register(LocationGroup)
admin.site.register(Report)
```

When I enter the admin page for Report, it shows a nice multiple choice field. How can I add the same multiple choice field in LocationGroup? I can access all Reports by calling LocationGroup.report_set.all()

Comment: Related ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround I found was to follow the instructions for [ManyToManyFields with intermediary models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models).  Even though you're not using the 'through' model feature, just pretend as if you were and create a stub model with the necessary ForeignKey.

```
# models:  make sure the naming convention matches what ManyToManyField would create
class Report_LocationGroups(models.Model):
    locationgroup = models.ForeignKey(LocationGroup)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)

# admin
class ReportInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Report_LocationGroups

class LocationGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = ReportInline,
```

Comment: Easiest, but still a hack. I wish Django could support this is in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

I think yon can combine this sample code ([source](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897)) wich breaks sync_db

```
class ItemType(meta.Model):
    name = meta.CharField(maxlength=100)
    description = meta.CharField(maxlength=250)
    properties = meta.ManyToManyField('PropertyType',
            db_table='app_propertytype_itemtypes')

class PropertyType(meta.Model):
    name = meta.CharField(maxlength=100)
    itemtypes = meta.ManyToManyField(ItemType)
```

with [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1295/)

```
class ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb(models.ManyToManyField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.creates_table = False
```

to obtain something like

```
class ItemType(meta.Model):
    name = meta.CharField(maxlength=100)
    description = meta.CharField(maxlength=250)
    properties = meta.ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb('PropertyType',
            db_table='app_propertytype_itemtypes')

class PropertyType(meta.Model):
    name = meta.CharField(maxlength=100)
    itemtypes = meta.ManyToManyField(ItemType)
```

**Disclaimer** : this is just a rough idea

Edit: There is probably someting to do with [Django's 1.1 Proxy Models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

Answer (score 1):

I think what are you are looking for is [admin inlines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). In your admin.py you will want to add something like this:

```
class LocationGroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LocationGroup

class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ LocationGroupInline, ]
admin.site.register(Report, ReportAdmin)
admin.site.register(LocationGroup)
```

There are many options to include in LocationGroupInline if you want to further configure the inline display of the related model. Two of these options are **form** and **formset**, which will let you use custom Django Form and FormSet classes to further customize the look and feel of the inline model admin. Using this you can create a simple Form that displays just the multiple choice field you want (except for a M2M field it will not be possible to display as a single drop down, but a multiple select box). For example:

```
class MyLocationGroupForm(forms.Form):
    location = forms.MultipleModelChoiceField(
           queryset=LocationGroup.objects.all())

class LocationGroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LocationGroup
    form = MyLocationGroupForm
```

Comment: Report admin will have LocationGroups inlined by default, the question was how to do the reverse.  Regardless, this will raise an exception that LocationGroup has no ForeignKey to ReportAdmin.