# Django admin: how do I add an unrelated model field to a model change/add page?

Tags: django, django-admin, modeladmin

I have the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class Foo_bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    ...
```

In the admin, I want it so that in the Foo change/add page, you can specify a Bar object, and on save I want to create a Foo_bar object to represent the relationship. How can I do this through customizing the Admin site/ModelAdmins? Note that inlining isn't quite what I need because there is no explicit foreign key relationship between foo and bar. And second, I don't actually want to edit bar objects, I just want to choose from amongst the ones that are in the system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't just want a [ManyToManyField](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/)?  In the admin, this would manifest as a multiple-selection list of `Bar` objects.  Look at the group selection part of the admin for `User`.

If you need additional data attached to the relationship, you could [use a `through` parameter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    bars = models.ManyToManyField("Bar", related_name="foos", through="Foo_bar")
```

You'll need to add Foo_bar to the admin in order to edit these additional parameters in the admin.

Comment: Thanks! If I declare the ManyToManyField in Bar, can I get it to show up in Foo?

Comment: That's what the `related_name` parameter is all about.  Using my example, every `Foo` object has a `bars` field that is the M2M, and every `Bar` object has a `foos` field that is the reverse-going relation.  So it doesn't matter much which one you put the `ManyToManyField` in; you'll get both directions automatically.  Just don't put it in both models, or it will mock you.

Comment: Also check out the `limit_choices_to` parameter, described in `ForeignKey`'s docs, for a way to keep the size of the list down.  One more thing: in the admin, the relation only shows up in the admin for the model that declared the `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Are you sure just adding 'related_name' will make the Foo listbox show up in Bar's admin page? According to this, you might need to do more than that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339409/how-to-add-bi-directional-manytomanyfields-in-django-admin

Comment: See the last sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: It seems I misinterpreted your first comment.  I thought you were speaking of the models, not the admins.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. You could create a custom form for your `Foo` model and add a field containing the `Bar.objects.all()` queryset to it. then override the ModelAdmin's default `save_form()` method to create a new `Bar` instance upon saving the object.
2. You could create a custom Field class and add it to you `Foo` model, and class this functionality via a ´post_save` signal...

Answer (score 0):

For those actually looking to add an unrelated model field to add/change, use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

```
from django import forms

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Foo.objects.all())
    bar = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Bar.objects.all())
```

Then simply add the form to the ModelAdmin's add_form/change_form