# django admin many-to-many intermediary models using through= and filter_horizontal

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is how my models look:

```
class QuestionTagM2M(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag')
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through=QuestionTagM2M, related_name='questions')
```

All I really wanted to do was add a timestamp when a given manytomany relationship was created. It makes sense, but it also adds a bit of complexity. Apart from removing the .add() functionality [despite the fact that the only field I'm really adding is auto-created so it technically shouldn't interfere with this anymore]. But I can live with that, as I don't mind doing the extra `QuestionTagM2M.objects.create(question=,tag=)` instead if it means gaining the additional timestamp functionality.

My issue is I really would love to be able to preserve my `filter_horizontal` javascript widget in the admin. I know the docs say I can use an inline instead, but this is just too unwieldy because there are no additional fields that would actually be in the inline apart from the foreign key to the `Tag` anyway.

Also, in the larger scheme of my database schema, my `Question` objects are already displayed as an inline on my admin page, and since Django doesn't support nested inlines in the admin [yet], I have no way of selecting tags for a given question.

Is there any way to override `formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs)` or something similar to allow for my usage of the nifty `filter_horizontal` widget and the auto creation of the `date_added` column to the database?

This seems like something that django should be able to do natively as long as you specify that all columns in the intermediate are automatically created (other than the foreign keys) perhaps with `auto_created=True`? or something of the like

Comment: `tag_set` and `question_set` are just [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/). You can extend `django.db.models.Manager` and add all the superpowers you want to it. If you declare them with the default names on your Models, they won't get overwritten by the default ones, Django won't get in your way. I've used that to change the behaviour of the `.objects.` Manager of some of my Models.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are *ways* to do this

- As provided by @obsoleter in [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110606/django-admin-many-to-many-intermediary-models-using-through-and-filter-horizont/10203192?noredirect=1#comment18228487_10203192) : set `QuestionTagM2M._meta.auto_created = True` and deal w/ syncdb matters.
- Dynamically add `date_added` field to the M2M model of `Question` model in models.py

  ```
  class Question(models.Model):
      # use auto-created M2M model
      tags = models.ManyToMany(Tag, related_name='questions')


  # add date_added field to the M2M model
  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True).contribute_to_class(
           Question.tags.through, 'date_added')
  ```

  Then you could use it in admin as normal `ManyToManyField`.
  In Python shell, use `Question.tags.through` to refer the M2M model.

  *Note*, If you don't use `South`, then `syncdb` is enough; If you do, `South` does not like 
  this way and will not freeze `date_added` field, you need to manually write migration to add/remove the corresponding column.
- Customize ModelAdmin:

  1. Don't define `fields` inside customized ModelAdmin, only define `filter_horizontal`. This will bypass the field validation mentioned in Irfan's answer.
  2. Customize `formfield_for_dbfield()` or `formfield_for_manytomany()` to make Django admin to use `widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple` for the `tags` field.
  3. Customize `save_related()` method inside your ModelAdmin class, like

```
def save_related(self, request, form, *args, **kwargs):
    tags = form.cleaned_data.pop('tags', ())
    question = form.instance
    for tag in tags:
        QuestionTagM2M.objects.create(tag=tag, question=question)
    super(QuestionAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, *args, **kwargs)
```

- Also, you could patch `__set__()` of the `ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor` field descriptor of ManyToManyField for `date_added` to save M2M instance w/o raise exception.

Comment: I found another option by reading the source for the `BaseModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany` method in `django/contrib/admin/options.py`.  You can trick the ModelAdmin into using your custom many to many table for horizonal/vertical filters by setting `QuestionTagM2M._meta.auto_created = True`

Comment: @obsoleter this breaks syncdb however you can work around it by doing if not 'syncdb' in sys.argv: in the Meta class. Still hacky but the best way I've seen to do this.

Comment: An implementation example of @obsoleter's approach can be found in [Django ticket 12203](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12203#comment:22).

Answer (score 4):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

> When you specify an intermediary model using the through argument to a ManyToManyField, the admin will not display a widget by default. This is because each instance of that intermediary model requires more information than could be displayed in a single widget, and the layout required for multiple widgets will vary depending on the intermediate model.

However, you can try including the tags field explicitly by using `fields = ('tags',)` in admin. This will cause this validation exception

> 'QuestionAdmin.fields' can't include the ManyToManyField field 'tags' because 'tags' manually specifies a 'through' model.

This validation is implemented in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/validation.py#L256

```
        if isinstance(f, models.ManyToManyField) and not f.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("'%s.%s' "
                "can't include the ManyToManyField field '%s' because "
                "'%s' manually specifies a 'through' model." % (
                    cls.__name__, label, field, field))
```

I don't think that you can bypass this validation unless you implement your own custom field to be used as ManyToManyField.

Comment: Another possibility would be to tag the date_added field as read_only, which will allow `ModelAdmin` to pass validation. Obviously, you can't use this if you expect to modify `date_added` at a later point, but from your logic it doesn't seem you will have to.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct  - the docs have been updated. Please see @Daniel Rucci's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The docs may have changed since the previous answers were posted. I took a look at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models) link that @Irfan mentioned and it seems to be a more straight forward then it used to be.

Add an inline class to your `admin.py` and set the model to your M2M model

```
class QuestionTagM2MInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = QuestionTagM2M
    extra = 1
```

set `inlines` in your admin class to contain the Inline you just defined

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #...other stuff here
    inlines = (QuestionTagM2MInline,)
```

Don't forget to register this admin class

```
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

After doing the above when I click on a question I have the form to do all the normal edits on it and below that are a list of the elements in my m2m relationship where I can add entries or edit existing ones.

Comment: This answer is the most correct and recent. The docs now cover how to do this in great detail. It's also worth noting that explicit field declaration now works as shown in Irfan's answer.

Comment: does not preserve `filter_horizontal` admin javascript